# Getting data from PHP to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

So, I want to create dynamic donut chart, where the datas are from mySql database. But, the problem is in that chart, the datas get from JSON.

My question, how to use datas from PHP to be use for JSON datas. here're my progress so far :

```
<?php    

$query_A = "SELECT COUNT(category) as catg FROM mydata ORDER BY category";
$result_A = mysql_query($query_A);

$query_B = "SELECT COUNT(category) as catg FROM mydata ORDER BY category";
$result_B = mysql_query($query_B);

//Print JSON

$prefix = '';
"[\n";
while ( $row_A = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result_A ) ) {
  $prefix . " {<br>";
  '  "category": "' . "A" . '",' . "<br>";
  '  "value": ' . $row_A['catg'] . ',' . "<br>";
  " }";
  $prefix = ",\n";
}
while ( $row_B = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result_B ) ) {
  $prefix . " {<br>";
  '  "category": "' . "B" . '",' . "<br>";
  '  "value": ' . $row_B['catg'] . ',' . "<br>";
  " }";
  $prefix = ",\n";
}
"\n]";

?>
```

And here're JSON datas from that donut chart :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
      "type": "pie",
      "theme": "light",
      "dataProvider": [ {
        "title": "New",
        "value": 200
      }, {
        "title": "Returning",
        "value": 9899
      }, {
        "title": "Back",
        "value": 900
      } ],
      "titleField": "title",
      "valueField": "value",
      "labelRadius": 10,

      "radius": "42%",
      "innerRadius": "60%",
      "labelText": "[[title]]",
      "export": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    } );
</script>
```

I want to use my mysql datas for that JSON datas. Thank you

Comment: why don't you try `json_encode()`??

Comment: use PHP function json_encode() to print out the result in Javascript.

Comment: Have you looked into the php documentation to search for a standard function? http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: The queries show no relation to the desired result (regardless of the weird manual json building attempt) - voting to close as unclear

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy function called [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode). Simply run your data through this function.

```
$json = json_encode($data); // returns a JSON string
```

By the way, have you tried googling for "PHP create JSON" or something similar? The time it took you to write this question, you would already have found a solution. Not to mention the time you wasted on trying to create the JSON yourself.

Just saying, you can save a lot of time by asking a search engine … you are usually not the first to have a particular problem.

Comment: In your while loop, push your data in an array and then encode the array using json_encode. Return the encoded value and you are good to go

Comment: Thank you for your advice sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why there are two identical queries but that said.

```
<?php
    $query_A = "SELECT COUNT(`category`) as 'catg' FROM `mydata` ORDER BY `category`";
    $result_A = mysql_query( $query_A );

    $query_B = "SELECT COUNT(`category`) as 'catg' FROM `mydata` ORDER BY `category`";
    $result_B = mysql_query( $query_B );

    if( $result_A ){
        $data=array();
        while ( $row_A = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result_A ) ) {
            $data[]=array('category'=>'A', 'value'=>$row_A['catg'] );
        }
        $json_A=json_encode( $data );
    }

    if( $result_B ){
        $data=array();
        while ( $row_B = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result_B ) ) {
            $data[]=array('category'=>'B', 'value'=>$row_B['catg'] );
        }
        $json_B=json_encode( $data );
    }
?>
```

Then, in your javascript you could do this:-

```
var json_a=<?php echo $json_A;?>;
var json_b=<?php echo $json_B;?>;
```